# R from CRAN vs R from Conda

Tags: r, conda

I am learning how to use R using Coursera and I have installed it using the link from R-Project; however, I have previously coded using Jupyter and I like that better than using the terminal. Will there be some interference by installing r-essentials from conda? Or do I have to install R from R-project before using r-essentials?

Comment: First download R from [HERE](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/) (e.g. for windows) and then install RStudio from [HERE](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/). Then, open RStudio and enjoy coding.

Comment: I believe @989's suggestion is to try the R-Notebook feature as provided by RStudio. Many find RStudio's interface to be superior to the basic R terminal (I agree) even without notebooks, and if you like Jupyter then the notebook flow may be better. (Sorry, I don't know about 'conda R', don't know for certain of any conflicts.)

Comment: Most (R) people I know follow a pretty simple rule: "don't use conda".  Works for me.

Comment: Nice! I didn't know RStudio had a notebook! Sweet, thanx!

Comment: I have used R in jupyter notebooks and rStudio on the same computer (both Mac's and PC's ) with absolutely NO PROBLEMS at all. You will need to be aware that the jupyter notebook operates in a virtual environment, so it does not see your libraries installed via R in console or rStudio. You have two options...make it see your current R libraries but setting a path, or install them again via conda and let that instance of R manage them for Jupyter. Either way works fine.

Comment: Thank you @sconfluentus, that's exactly what I was looking for! :)

Answer (score 1):

I use R as an amateur by the last 5 years, and I will do my best to help you in your 2 questions:

- Will there be some interference by installing r-essentials from conda?

R: No. Conda works with a separate environment, as far as I know.  So you will be fine.

- Or do I have to install R from R-project before using r-essentials?

R: I suppose you are installing r-essentials from a package manager (apt-get).  If you are doing this, the package manager, most of times, will take care of the dependencies for you.  So, in a typical situation, you would not be needed to install from CRAN beforehand.

My tip to you - Install R outside Anaconda (using CRAN Packages).  You will always get the most updated R version, and the risk of getting into problems because of the integrations and repositories will be diminished.

Good luck!